# No resource identifier found for attribute 'font' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

I'm using [Font Binder](https://github.com/nitrico/FontBinder) library but I get this error when I compile

```
C:\Users\Gonzalo\AndroidStudioProjects\firebase\app\build\intermediates\data-binding-layout-out\debug\layout\fragment_edit_name.xml

Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'font' in package 'android'
```

I set databinding in my gradle

```
 dataBinding {
        enabled  true
    }
```

I add the library

```
compile 'com.github.nitrico.fontbinder:fontbinder:1.0.3'
```

and this is my XML

```
<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="Fecha"
                android:font='@{"avquest"}'
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>
```

The font is in

```
\app\src\main\assets\fonts
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved here in github repo talking with the owner

https://github.com/nitrico/FontBinder/issues/2

Comment: It is better to include a short answer of the solution when adding a link. The link may expire any time, like when repo is deleted.